# Why does my C dynamic array give me access violation?

Tags: c

Here is the code I have.

```
int *arr;  // Indented this line
int sizeOfArr = 0;

printf("Enter size of arr.\n");
scanf("%d", &sizeOfArr);

arr = malloc(sizeOfArr * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArr; i++) {

    scanf("%d", arr[i]);

}
```

For example, if the size of the dynamic array is 5, and I proceed to enter the input "1 2 3 4 5", the entire program crashes and gives me access violation.

Comment: `scanf("%d", arr[i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` or `scanf("%d", arr + i);`

Comment: Also, try to make sure the proper header files are included in case you forgot.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you, that seemed to work! However, why must I use the address pointer, when arr is already a pointer itself?

Comment: @user2519193 `arr[i]` isn't pointer.

Comment: `arr[i]` is the same as `*(arr+i)`,, in both cases the pointer is dereferenced. `scanf` needs a pointer as its 2nd argument.

Comment: @user2519193: Yes, `arr` is a pointer. But `arr[i]` is *not* a pointer. You are supplying `arr[i]` to `scanf`. And `scanf` wants a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to store array elements you need to use `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` instead of 
`scanf("%d", arr[i]);`

`&` in `C` is used to refer to address of a variable. So,by using `&arr[i]` you are telling your program to store the input variable at `ith` index of array  `arr[]`.

So the correct code will be

```
int *arr;
int sizeOfArr = 0;

printf("Enter size of arr.\n");
scanf("%d", &sizeOfArr);

arr = malloc(sizeOfArr * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArr; i++) {

    scanf("%d", &arr[i]); //notice the diff here

}
```